SF CLI data import tree: Maximum call stack size exceeded
I've been using the data import tree CLI command for quite some time to import parent-child data after deployments. My current dataset includes 666 parent and 4,621 child items in JSON files, totaling 5,287 records. I've never encountered any issues with the import process until I updated to the latest version of the CLI.
My current CLI version is @salesforce/cli/2.54.6 win32-x64 node-v20.16.0. When I attempt to run the import, I receive the following error:

sf data import tree --plan data/my-data-plan.json --target-org devOrg


Error (RangeError): Maximum call stack size exceeded

Despite this error, some records are still imported into the org:

The query SELECT COUNT() FROM Parent returns 666 records, which is
correct.
However, the query SELECT COUNT() FROM Child returns only
4,092 records, meaning 529 records are missing due to the error.

The only solution I've found so far is to downgrade to an older CLI version
@salesforce/cli/2.40.7 win32-x64 node-v20.9.0, where the import completes successfully and all records are imported correctly.
It appears that the newer SF CLI version struggles with a large number of child records. Based on my understanding, the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error might be related to too many loop iterations.
Has anyone else experienced this issue, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve it?
Thanks!

As per Documentation, If you used the --plan flag when exporting the data to generate a plan definition file, use the --plan flag to reference the file when you import. If you're not using a plan, use the --files flag to list the files. If you specify multiple JSON files that depend on each other in a parent-child relationship, be sure you list them in the correct order.

@TusharJadav I do use "--plan" attribute for import command. If that was the issue it would fail a long time ago not after the last CLI version update.

The root cause is related to new CLI commands.
sf data import/export tree SF CLI commands have been rewritten recently - https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2738
They rolled out the new implementation on July, 10th. That's why the older SF CLI (v2.40.7 - from May) could import all records because it still used the old implementation.
It's still possible to use the old implementation in the newest SF CLI (no need to downgrade the version):

sf data import legacy tree

Salesforce will retire the old implementation on Nov, 10th 2024.
